# Play framework error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when executing play run

Tags: playframework, web-frameworks

I always get this exception when running command: play run

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
12:53:46,970 INFO  ~ Starting D:\Study\Scala\app1
12:53:46,991 INFO  ~ Module scala is available (D:\Study\Scala\play-1.1.2\module
s\scala-0.9.1)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.data.binding.Binder
.register(Ljava/lang/Class;Lplay/data/binding/TypeBinder;)V
        at play.scalasupport.ScalaPlugin.onLoad(ScalaPlugin.scala:27)
        at play.Play.loadPlugins(Play.java:587)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:268)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:131)
```

Note: 
I installed my scala module by downloading the file scala-0.9.1.zip from the website and copy it to \play-1.1.2\modules\, I did so because we have proxy in my company computer, I failed to install the scala module by running `play install scala`

I am using Windows7 and java 1.6. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you extract the module and added it to your dependencies?

Comment: Maybe Scala 0.9.1 is not really compatible with Play 1.1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 0.9.1 requires Play 1.2.2 or newer, that's why it's failing